# Laravel QueryBuilder - Select N rows for each foreign key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to retrieve the latest 5 rows for each foreign key in a table, so imagine the following database structure:

```
CATEGORY (id, name)
ARTICLE (id, category_id, title)
```

I want do something like this:

```
Article::where("category_id", 1)
       -> latest()
       -> limit(5)
       -> get();

Article::where("category_id", 2)
       -> latest()
       -> limit(5)
       -> get();
```

And so on. How would I do this as a single query for all foreign keys?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per this:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/extending-eloquents-builder-to-eager-load-collections-w-limits?page=2

It isn't natively supported. Instead you have to use lazy eager loading.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Category::with(['article' => function($q){
        $q->orderBy('id', 'desc');
        $q->limit(5);
    })->get();
```

Of course you need to create foreign key relations in your models in order to use that functionality.

Here is documentation how to create relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Doesn't seem to work correctly. I added this to my category model: 

public function articles() { return $this -> hasMany(Article::class); }

but I only get records for the 4th foreign key?

Comment: You should get all categories with `article()` property where will be articles

Comment: Sorry, I'm still having trouble. What should the relationship method be on my category model?

Comment: The reason this isn't working, is because the resulting query generated by the builder is:

`select * from articles where category_id in (2, 5, 3, 4, 1, 6) limit 1`

which will simply return one record as opposed to one for each id. Anyone else have any ideas?